# Can JVM optimize out empty synchronized blocks?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the aggregator class which accumulates some data for a period of time. Now, after that time it's closed to accept a new data and is able to produce some aggregated results (perhaps computed by another thread than one performing the aggregation). Here's is how it looks like:

```
public class Aggregator{

    private volatile boolean closed;
    private Collection<Integer> data = new LinkedList<>();
    private int counter;
    private final Object mutex = new Object();

    public void close(){
        closed = true;
    }

    public boolean isClosed(){
       return closed;
    }

    public void add(Integer i){
        if(!closed){
            synchronized(mutex){
                if(__some_complex_condition__)
                    ++counter;
                data.add(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public Intger compute(){
        if(closed){
            synchronized(mutext){ }    //<----- IS IT SAFE???
                                       //to ensure data-visibility
            Integer retVal;
            //perform computation on data and counter
            return retVal;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is it reliable to use empty synchronized block to just ensure data-consistency. I think yes, it is as long as the contract of this class tells us that no new data will be accept once `Aggregator` is closed and it's not possible to compute the value if it's still open.

But I'm not quite sure about that. Maybe `JVM` just optmize empty-synchronized block away and I'll get into big troubles...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It's sad. Is there another common way out? I'd like to make the synchronized block as min as possible.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch What do you mean don't move Integer?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Because I want a thread performing the computation see the correct values of the fields for the computation, yet I want to minimize synchronized block. Therefore I need some memory barrier (`synchronized` block in this particular case).

Comment: However, beware of typos. `mutex` != `mutext`.